# Add a file name to a Path object

Tags: java, path, filenames

I have a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) object leading to a folder.

```
Path pathToFolder = Paths.get( "/Users/someuser/" );
```

…or the recommended way using [`Path.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)):

```
Path pathToFolder = Path.of( "/Users/someuser/" );
```

I want to create a file named "whatever.text" in that folder using [`Files.newBufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) where I pass a `Path` object.

```
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter( pathToFile ) ;
```

How do I transform my `pathToFolder` to get a `Path` object `pathToFile`?

I need more than mere string manipulation, as these are soft-coded values determined at runtime. And I am trying to be cross-platform as well.

This seems like an obvious question, but I could not find any existing post (the terminology does make searching tricky).

Comment: Is `pathToFile` equal to `pathToFolder.resolve("whatever.text");`?

Comment: @KevinO Is that the purpose of [`Path::resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.lang.String)), to join the pieces into a single `Path` object?

Comment: Yes, the `.resolve(...)` will join, in the file system appropriate fashion, the filename (or another directory) to the previous `Path` instance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.lang.String-):

> Converts a given path string to a Path and resolves it against this Path in exactly the manner specified by the resolve method. For example, suppose that the name separator is "/" and a path represents "foo/bar", then invoking this method with the path string "gus" will result in the Path "foo/bar/gus".

So you should use this:

```
Path pathToFolder = Path.of("/Users/someuser/");
Path pathToFile = pathToFolder.resolve("your-file-name");
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(pathToFile);
```